# Calling a python kivy callback every 30 seconds while Switch is active?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm building an app in python kivy.

I've got a switch widget (`switch1`), and when it's active I want to print '*Hello world'* **every 30 seconds**.

In my attempt below I first define a callback (`switch1_callback`) that prints '*Hello world*'. Then I define another callback (`timely_switch1_callback`) with `Clock.schedule_interval()` that calls `switch1_callback`. `timely_switch1_callback` is bound to `switch1`.

I keep getting an error message `(TypeError: switch1_callback() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given)`.

Thanks for any help!

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle, Color
from kivy.clock import Clock

kv = '''
<PrettySwitch>:
size_hint: None, None
size: 300, 300
canvas:
    Color:
        rgba: 0, 0, 1, 1    
    Rectangle:
        size: self.size  
        pos: self.pos
Switch:
    id: switch1                 
    pos: 150, 150
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 100, 50
    active: True   
    on_active: root.timely_switch1_callback()
    
'''
class PrettySwitch(FloatLayout):

    def switch1_callback(self):
        print('Hello world')

    def timely_switch1_callback(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.switch1_callback, 30)
    
class SwitchApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(kv)
        return PrettySwitch()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SwitchApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your definition of `switch1_callback()` to take 2 arguments:

```
def switch1_callback(self, dt):
```

The `dt` argument is added by `Clock.schedule_interval()`.